# high-resolution-plot as png-graphic with fixed font size in R

Tags: r, plot

I want to save my plots as a `png`-file to use them in other documents. They need to have a fixed font size and a high resolution.

Simple plot but with low quality.

```
png('myfile.png', pointsize=10)
plot(cars)
dev.off()
```

The 'res' parameter here doesn't work. And I think it will change the real size of my font, too.

```
png('myfile.png', pointsize=10, res=1200)
plot(cars)
Fehler in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
png(filename = "Rplot%03d.png",
    width = 480, height = 480, units = "px", pointsize = 12,
     bg = "white",  res = NA, ...,
    type = c("cairo", "cairo-png", "Xlib", "quartz"), antialias)
```

Correct way for you will be to use the width and height to get the required resolution

IF you want to have fixed font size you can use cex parameter as some function of the width and height
so for example

```
height = width * 1.2 
cex = width/300  

When width = 400 
Height = 480 
Cex = 1.33
```

Just find the right cex conversion parameter as a function of width

Check out these 3 simple codes

```
width=600
cex=width/300
png('myfile1.png', pointsize=10, width=width , height=width*1.2)
plot(cars , cex.lab=cex, cex=cex)
dev.off()

width=900
cex=width/300
png('myfile2.png', pointsize=10, width=width , height=width*1.2)
plot(cars , cex.lab=cex, cex=cex)
dev.off()

width=1200
cex=width/300
png('myfile3.png', pointsize=10, width=width , height=width*1.2)
plot(cars , cex.lab=cex, cex=cex)
dev.off()
```

The font size remains constant in proportion with the plot resolution